# Adobe AIR and PDF framework

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, air

Is there any way to handle PDF in Adobe AIR?
I don't want just to open it, I need to programmatically use it. Example: extracting pages, rotate pages, add gfx elements to a page, read annotations. I would need a complete framework to handle PDF in AIR.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PurePDF](http://blog.sephiroth.it/projects/purepdf/), it is a port of the famous [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) java and C# library

That's the closest you will get to be able to do in ActionScript what you describe above.

Cheers